# How to separate core logic and logging code in a Ruby application?

Tags: ruby, logging

I am looking for a general way to maintain a separation of core logic and logging/debugging/terminal output code in a Ruby application's codebase.  Ideally, I would like to have a separate "tracer" codebase parallel to that of my application core (the 'lib' directory in a typical Ruby project). The tracer code would live in a special directory (perhaps called "trace") in the same way that unit tests often live in a parallel structure in the test/spec directory.  Tracer files would extend target classes with wrappers for various methods.  These wrappers would do things like writing to a log, setting a breakpoint (e.g. with [pry](https://github.com/pry/pry)'s' `binding.pry`) or incrementing a progress bar whenever the method returned.  The loading of the tracer code could then be controlled by a single switch.

I have done some research and come up mostly blank.  I've found some pieces of the functionality I'm after; for example, the standard library's [Tracer](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0//libdoc/tracer/rdoc/Tracer.html) class and the [method_decorators gem](https://github.com/michaelfairley/method_decorators).  But I am wondering there is a more complete solution out there, something analogous to rspec for testing.  Does such a thing exist?  Or are there perhaps other ways of dealing with this problem?

Comment: I'm having a hard time relating anything regarding rspec to logging; what precisely do you want this to look like and/or do? Logging by its nature is code- and need-specific; *what* do you want to log? How would you go *in* to a method and do "something" at an arbitrary location? *Wrapping* functionality is easy, but it's unclear if that's what you want.

Comment: @Dave There is nothing about the functionality I'm looking for that is similar to RSpec; the similarity is in the way that RSpec (or other unit test frameworks) is typically used to construct a "layer" of code that is structured parallel to and runs on top of the actual application code, loaded only when one wants to run unit tests.  A logging/command-line-output layer could be structured in a similar way.  If it matters, what I currently want to log is intermediate steps in multistep mathematical calculations, but that's really besides the point.  (continued below)

Comment: @Dave I'm looking for a framework/library that offers a general solution to the separation of logic from reporting on it as it is carried out.  Yes, the content of what is logged is code-specific-- but the separation of logging directives from logic is not.

Comment: RSpec is only "in parallel" in that you put stuff in the same directory/module hierarchy as your code. The answer depends entirely upon how those "steps" are implemented (e.g., how they're broken up). If it's multiple *methods*, then simple "around" advice should work, you'd just log inputs and outputs. If it's *not*, e.g., you need to break in to the *middle* of a method, you'd have to play games with AST manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

If you, for instance, are looking at enabling this code only in development, then you can add an initializer in rails: /config/initializers

```
if( Rails.env.development?)
  require "logging_wrappers"
end
```

In your *lib/* folder, you can add your extensions into lib/logging_wrappers.rb

To override the find_by_id function on your User model, simply add the following:

```
class User
  alias_method :unlogged__find_by_id, :find_by_id

  def find_by_id(id)
    Rails.logger.info "About to find by id"
    x = unlogged__find_by_id(id)
    if (x.blank?)
      Rails.logger.info "We didn't find any users"
    end
  end
```

For more information on this technique, several good examples can be found at: http://yehudakatz.com/2009/01/18/other-ways-to-wrap-a-method/

Comment: Thanks for this.  Certainly the sort of loading using an environment switch is what I plan on, but I'm not using Rails.  I also appreciate the link to the wrapping methods.